# Is an App Engine instance required for accessing Datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Do I need to deploy an App (even a dummy one) on the App Engine in order to use the Datastore service using the google-cloud-datastore Java API from a client such as a Compute Engine running in the google cloud?

Comment: why you think you cant? what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need to deploy an AppEngine app to access the Google Cloud Datastore. You just need to create a project from the Console and you can connect to the Datastore in the project from anywhere using the [google-cloud-datasource](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-datastore) API.

Comment: And it can scale and perform quite well, read about how Pokemon Go runs on Google Container Engine and uses Datastore: https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2016/09/bringing-Pokemon-GO-to-life-on-Google-Cloud.html