# How do I use Google datastore for my web app which is NOT hosted in google app engine?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, web-hosting

I want to use datastore of google in my web app but do not want to host it in google app engine, I want to host it some other machine. So how i can use datastore in such web app ? 
will it be more economical ?

Answer (score 5):

You would need to follow the [Accessing the Cloud Datastore API from another platform](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/activate#accessing_the_short_product_name_api_from_another_platform) procedure:

> This section shows how to activate and access the Cloud Datastore API
>   from an external application running on a platform outside of Google
>   Cloud.
>
> 1. Enable the Cloud Datastore API for the project. You can enable the API for an existing project, or create a new project and then enable
>      the API.
>      [Enable the Cloud Datastore API](https://console.cloud.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=datastore.googleapis.com)
> 2. To use the Cloud Datastore API, your Cloud project requires an active App Engine application. Open the App Engine dashboard and
>      confirm your Cloud project has an active App Engine app.
>      [Open the App Engine dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine)
>
>    Create an App Engine app if needed. The app must not be disabled.
> 3. Go to the [Create service account key](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/serviceaccountkey) page.
> 4. Click the drop-down box below **Service account**, then click **New service account**.
> 5. Enter a name for the service account in **Name**.
> 6. Use the default **Service account ID** or generate a different one.
> 7. Select **JSON** in **Key type**.
> 8. Click **Create**.
> 9. Upon successful creation, your browser will download the private key. The Cloud Platform Console provides a prompt that displays the
>      private key file name. Note the file name so you can locate it, then
>      click Close to dismiss the prompt.
> 10. Your **Service Account** is the **Email address** displayed under the **Service Account** section.
> 11. Your **Private Key** is the file you just downloaded.
>
> At this point all services and authorizations are configured for your
>   project and you can start writing code or exploring the API.

You don't actually need to write code for the GAE app and deploy it, see [Is an App Engine instance required for accessing Datastore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40401696/is-an-app-engine-instance-required-for-accessing-datastore)

As for being more economical or not (I presume compared to running the app on GAE) - it depends **a lot** on the app's usage/scale, what the app does and how it does it.

Comment: does accessing datastore by method stated by you attract extra pricing by google ?

Comment: maybe, depending on where your machine is: networking costs (not charged for GAE apps): https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#network

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Cloud Endpoints

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/