# Google Cloud Datastore requires app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Im creating a Node.js website that probably won't have loads of traffic, and was looking into cheap solutions to host the site. Came across Google cloud services offering free usage for their services with limits. A f1-mirco is more than enough for my needs, but I will happily pay for some usage if it goes over by any chance.

I wanted to setup a linux centOS 7 on GCE (which I already did), and run my application and REST API on it. Now here comes the problem.

I tried to use Google's datastore service, but it sprung an app engine instance and without it datastore won't work.

**Is datastore entirely relying on app engine to function?? In the docs, it said if you use any of the client API, it requires app engine. What can I do to not use the client api and query data then? Don't want to use the app engine at the moment or datastore is just not for me then?**

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use Google datastore for my web app which is NOT hosted in google app engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42051453/how-do-i-use-google-datastore-for-my-web-app-which-is-not-hosted-in-google-app-e)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the underlying infrastructure of Cloud Datastore and App Engine are still tied together for creation, etc. So while creating an Cloud Datastore database also defines an App Engine instance for the project, **it doesn't require you to use** it. You don't get charged for App Engine either, unless you decide to deploy an App using it.

You should be totally fine use the Google Cloud Node client library on the f1 micro instance.

Comment: it's getting a bit clear after your input. However just to get more clarification, so this app engine doesn't use up my daily quota for 1 app engine instance. Thus I can deploy another instance somewhere and be fine.

Comment: Correct, it just defines which App Engine instance you would use, it doesn't deploy anything and doesn't count against your quota.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll flag it for the team

Comment: Is this still the case today?