# Is it possible to implement create a web project in Spring Boot + Datastore?

Tags: database, google-app-engine, spring-boot, google-cloud-datastore

I'm currently new to web developing and right now I started with a Spring Boot application which I converted to standard App Engine project. I'm wondering if it is possible to **not** convert my Spring Boot application to my App Engine project and still use Datastore as database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to use the Cloud Datastore from an app in the GAE flexible environment, from outside GAE or even from outside the Google Cloud. From [Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/migrating#datastore) (emphasis mine):

> You can access [Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs) **from anywhere** using the Cloud
>   Datastore API. Use the [Google Cloud client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/cloud-client-libraries) to store and
>   retrieve data from Cloud Datastore.
>
> The same Cloud Datastore data is available regardless of if you use
>   the App Engine libraries, the Google Cloud client libraries, or call
>   the API directly.

But you can't use the [GAE Standard Environment Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#google_app_engine_standard_environment_client_libraries), you have to use either the [Cloud Datastore Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries) or the [Cloud Datastore API v1](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis#cloud-datastore-api-v1).

Potentially of interest: the [Deploying to the App Engine Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/tools/intellij/docs/deploy-flex) guide happens to use a spring boot app as example.

Comment: Potentially relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42051453/how-do-i-use-google-datastore-for-my-web-app-which-is-not-hosted-in-google-app-e/42060551#42060551

Comment: Thank you Mr. Cornilescu, your effort is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How can I check if my project is in a GAE flexible environment though? I'm sorry I am quite new to web development and for now I'm just following tutorials like this one [here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/getting-started-with-google-app-engine-and-spring-boot-in-5-steps-2d0f8165c89)

Comment: If you have "env: flex" in your app.yaml it's GAE flex, otherwise it's standard. This might also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842772/how-to-tell-if-a-google-app-engine-documentation-page-applies-to-the-standard-or