# How to use google cloud datastore from google kubernetes engine(GKE)

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I have a requirement to store data in to google cloud datasore, My application is currently deployed on google kubernetes engine.The Tech Stack we are using is Java 11 Spring boot,GKE.Is there any documentation i can follow. The documents i found are the one which are deployed on the App Engine but we are deploying it into GKE.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'd expect it to work just the same, assuming you're following instructions for Google Cloud Datastore rather than AppEngine Standard Datastore. Have you actually run into problems yet? (It's not clear why you've included GCS and Firestore tags, btw.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use Google datastore for my web app which is NOT hosted in google app engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42051453/how-do-i-use-google-datastore-for-my-web-app-which-is-not-hosted-in-google-app-e)