# How can I write to another Google App Engine app?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How can I connect multiple Google App Engine apps to my one Django app engine service so that I can write to another apps datastore? Is this even possible?

Comment: Could not understand properly. Can you elaborate more.

Answer (score 4):

Directly accessing an app's datastore from another application is possible (you don't really need to write to the app itself for that!)

The fact that the other app is also a GAE app or not doesn't really matter, setting up the access control and accessing the respective datastore are the same.

I captured the details in [How do I use Google datastore for my web app which is NOT hosted in google app engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42051453/how-do-i-use-google-datastore-for-my-web-app-which-is-not-hosted-in-google-app-e/42060551#42060551)

If you don't want to give direct datastore access to the outside app then you could implement an inter-app communication protocol to achieve what you want:

- the app owning the datastore would act as a server for the other apps and would perform itself the datastore accesses on their behalf
- the other apps would be clients, sending requests to the server app to get it to perform the desired actions

With this approach you can implement any access control/restriction scheme you want on the server side, which is not really possible with the direct datastore access method.